# When I can't use templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Can someone explain to me when I can't use templates for generic functions or for generic classes?

I understand that templates are needed at compilation-time, hence, there exist cases where we can't use templates. But it's not clear to me , and I am unable to find examples of generic code that cannot be implemented with with templates (but can be implemented with polymorphism)

Comment: You need to post your non-working code so we can help you.  As currently asked your question is unclear as we have no idea what problem(s) you are having.  Please read how to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a template where you need *exactly one* type, such as the contents of a container. What you can do is have a non-template base, and a template derived class. This is known as *type erasure*.

A good example of this is `std::function<Foo(Bar)>`. There exist converting constructors from many different callable types that can match the signature `Foo(Bar)`, but they all result in the single type `std::function<Foo(Bar)>`, so you can have, say, a `std::vector<std::function<Foo(Bar)>>`.

```
extern Foo free_function(Bar);
extern Foo extra_args_function(Bar, Baz);

std::vector<std::function<Foo(Bar)>> foos
{
    [](Bar b) { return Foo(); },
    free_function,
    &Bar::to_Foo,
    std::bind(extra_args_function, std::placeholders::_1, Baz())
};
```

Additionally, you cannot make a template virtual method.